# how to time and toggle onclick events using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class, toggle, toggleclass

i have got a little issue with javascript(again). say i have some text and i want it to appear after a certain delay in time( 0.5 seconds) and onclick again it should disappear in an instant( without time delay)

so i want the code to toggle class of text which has time difference

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.show{display:block;}
.hide{display:none;}
</style>
<script>
function myfunc(){
the code here , 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="text" class="hide" onclick="myfunc()">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteteur</span>
</body>
```

i can figure the rest css and html all i need is the javascript code

Answer (score 2):

The things you're asking for are very basic to javascript.

Here's some documentation for you to read and learn from

- [timers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Timers)
- [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className) (how to set an element's class name)
- [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)
- [onclick event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick) (keep it [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) - avoid the use of inline event handlers if possible)

---

### Example | [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4emEL/1/)

I've composed a simple example for you to experiment and learn from

**Javascript**

```js
//Get the references to the elements we're working on
var my_text = document.getElementById("text"),
    my_toggler = document.getElementById("toggler");

//Set timeout delay to 500 milliseconds
var delay = 500;

//Declare timer callback function
function click_callback(){
    my_text.className = "show";
}

//Have a global variable to reset the timer
var my_timer;

//Declare the onclick event handler
function text_onclick(e){
    /*
        Clear the timer so we don't create more timers
        that will trigger the callback several times
    */
    if(my_timer) clearTimeout(my_timer);

    if(my_text.className === "hide")
        my_timer = setTimeout(click_callback, delay);
    else
        my_text.className = "hide";
}

//Add the event handler to the toggler element
my_toggler.onclick = text_onclick;
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="text" class="hide">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br />
        Etiam feugiat venenatis nulla vitae egestas.
    </div>
</div>
<div id="toggler">Toggle</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.show{ }

.hide{
    opacity: 0; /* Using opacity to "fill" the container */
    /* display: none; Also works, but acts differently.*/
}

#container{
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#toggler{
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: default;
    width: 50px;

    /* Make non-selectable*/
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#toggler:hover{
    background-color: #4488DD;
    border-color: lightgray;
    color: white;
}

#toggler:active{
    background-color: #66AAFF;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation but in ur fiddle the text disappears but then does not appear back , if u could then plz make the function happen onclick on a div which changes the class of text

Comment: Sooner or later you're gonna have to do this on your own! I'll update my answer as per your request ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunc()
{
    document.getElementById("text").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Do something after 0.5 seconds
    // Here you should display your text and bind the click event 
}, 500);
```